# Подскажите как работать с ref cursor или приведите пример

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc, plsql

Сколько не читал, пока для меня это не понятно. Посоветуйте что-то, или приведите пример.

Мне нужно, чтобы после написания пользователем данных в `JTextField` и нажатия кнопки `JButton`, данные добавлялись с помощью `ref cursor` в таблицу `SCOTT.DEPT`.

Comment: Попробуйте разделить задачу на части. Например, отделить модель от представления. Подумайте, чем отличается запись в базу после нажатия `JButton` от записи после выбора `JMenuitem`.

Comment: Если я вас правильно понял, то сначала надо загрузить драйвера БД, моста, создать подключение, создать Statement'а, выполнить запрос?

Comment: Я имел в виду, что получение данных из `JTextField` и запись данных в базу данных — это две совершенно не связанные задачи. И решать их надо по отдельности.

Comment: уразумел, спасибо

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вот самый простой и рабочий пример (схема HR) с указателем на курсор, для понимания как с ним работать, где первый вызов с `OUT` парамртром , второй с `IN`:

```
import oracle.jdbc.*;
import java.sql.*;

public class TestRefCursor {
    public static void main (String[] args) {
        try {
            Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection ("jdbc:oracle:thin:@server/service", "hr", "hr");
            CallableStatement cso = conn.prepareCall (""
                +"declare rc sys_refcursor; "
                +"begin open rc FOR "
                +"    select department_id, department_name "
                +"    from departments order by department_id; "
                +"? := rc;  end;"); 
            cso.registerOutParameter (1, OracleTypes.CURSOR);
            cso.execute ();
            ResultSet rset = (ResultSet)cso.getObject (1);
            if (rset.next ()) {
                System.out.println (rset.getInt ("department_id")+"\t"+rset.getString ("department_name")); }
            
            CallableStatement csi = conn.prepareCall (""
                +"declare rc sys_refcursor; no number; name varchar2 (32);" 
                +"begin rc := ?; fetch rc into no, name; ? := no; ? := name; end;");  
            ((OracleCallableStatement)csi).setCursor (1, rset);
            csi.registerOutParameter (2, OracleTypes.INTEGER);
            csi.registerOutParameter (3, OracleTypes.VARCHAR);
            csi.execute ();
            System.out.println (csi.getInt (2)+"\t"+csi.getString (3)+"\t*** fetch in PL/SQL ***");
            while (rset.next ()) {
                System.out.println (rset.getInt ("department_id")+"\t"+rset.getString ("department_name")); }
        } catch (Exception e) { e.printStackTrace (); }
    }
}
```

Выведет такой результат:

```
10      Administration
110     Accounting      *** fetch in PL/SQL ***
20      Marketing
30      Purchasing
...
```